# Extract mysql query from tcpdump

Tags: mysql, tcp, packet, tcpdump, amazon-aurora

I'm using `tcpdump` to capture TCP packet from port 3306 which is forwarded to MySQL server

```
sudo tcpdump -X -i ens5 -s 0 -tttt dst port 3306
```

and executed SQL `select * from user_trading_volume limit 1` from MySQL client

the captured result is below

```
2020-05-27 07:46:44.330084 IP ip-10-0-1-33.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal.59750 > ip-10-30-1-179.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 1945:2020, ack 16715, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3790143765 ecr 4258512397], length 75
0x0000:  4500 007f 54fb 4000 4006 ce8c 0a00 0121  E...T.@.@......!
0x0010:  0a1e 01b3 e966 0cea 76a0 9245 c975 2466  .....f..v..E.u$f
0x0020:  8018 0200 1763 0000 0101 080a e1e9 0115  .....c..........
0x0030:  fdd3 be0d 1703 0300 46f5 525d 17c9 20ac  ........F.R]....
0x0040:  62e6 fcdc ba82 11fc 91c2 c187 7ca8 a542  b...........|..B
0x0050:  6ed8 a1fa b1d8 01bd 1240 61d9 686e 183d  n........@a.hn.=
0x0060:  f2fc 9b9a a62d c212 8d4d e1c6 e67a 4bdc  .....-...M...zK.
0x0070:  ea2e 75dc 68cf 5c45 1721 2ced c511 ca    ..u.h.\E.!,....

2020-05-27 07:46:44.331029 IP ip-10-0-1-33.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal.59750 > ip-10-30-1-179.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal.mysql: Flags [.], ack 17677, win 505, options [nop,nop,TS val 3790143766 ecr 4258513778], length 0
0x0000:  4500 0034 54fc 4000 4006 ced6 0a00 0121  E..4T.@.@......!
0x0010:  0a1e 01b3 e966 0cea 76a0 9290 c975 2828  .....f..v....u((
0x0020:  8010 01f9 1718 0000 0101 080a e1e9 0116  ................
0x0030:  fdd3 c372
```

but the captured packet was not readable (Which means not ASCII)

I'm using AWS aurora (mysql 5.7)

Does anyone knows what this packet means?

PS.
I tried it in my local environment too and could retrieve matching SQL from packet as below
(run mysql within docker container and executed query through mysql workbench)

```
16:59:46.628631 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59587, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 98)
    view-localhost.52652 > view-localhost.3318: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfe56 (incorrect -> 0x1538), seq 61:107, ack 899, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 632447157 ecr 632447154], length 46
E..b..@.@.S...............@....=.....V.....
%.`.%.`.*....select * from user_trading_volume limit 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the first byte, this looks like two raw IP packets (45 => IP version **4**, typical 20byte header (**5** * 4 bytes). Wikipedia has more info on [IP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header).

### Converting to pcap

Thus, we should be able to convert this back to a pcap. We can convert this text dump to a packet capture using [text2pcap](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html), which is a command line utility that ships with Wireshark.

With the given text as file `temp`, we can convert it into a pcap

```sh
$ cat temp | grep -v 2020 | cut -c3-49 | sed 's/ \(\w\w\)/ \1 /g' \
 | text2pcap -l 101 - temp.pcap
Input from: Standard input
Output to: temp.pcap
Output format: pcap
Wrote packet of 127 bytes.
Wrote packet of 52 bytes.
Read 2 potential packets, wrote 2 packets (235 bytes).
```

#### Sanitizing text2pcap input

Here, we sanitize input so that text2pcap doesn't fail:

- `grev -v 2020`: remove the 2020... info lines
- `cut -c3-49`: Remove the preceding 0x and ASCII representation
- `sed 's/ \(\w\w\)/ \1 /g'`: Convert hexdump from 2 bytes then space to 1 byte then space (`09ab` => `09 ab`)
- `text2pcap -l 101 - temp.cap`: Read from stdin and write to temp.pcap as Raw IP packets (see below)

You can now view this capture in [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see what the fields are.

#### Figuring out the linklayer number for text2pcap

Going back to the initial byte, that byte starts the IP layer when normally a link layer like Ethernet starts the packet. That means that we can't use the typical link layer of 1 (Ethernet). The link layer for raw IP  is 101, so we need to specify that with text2pcap as `-l 101`. `-` is standard input, and then we write the file as temp.pcap.

### What does the packet mean?

When loaded in Wireshark, packet 1 has a payload of 75 bytes, and it's not ASCII. You will probably want to manually decode these bytes using the [MySQL protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.12/page_protocol_basics.html) reference. Because according to docs,

> The MySQL protocol is used between MySQL Clients and a MySQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
But the problem was that that packet was encrypted data as the packet sent via https protocol (which I didn't mean... haha...)

Comment: You can extract data from https captures, but you need to have set it up on the client/server beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

you can using tcpdump capture the data, and then using option `-w` redirect it to files.
then using wireshark to load it.

https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolstcpdump.html